# Unhandled exception at 0x0000007b in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, masm, masm32

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x0000007b in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation`

Firstly I am unsure what happens in this instruction: `MOV EAX, 100`
Because I already store 123 into EAX. When I debugged the program, it states that EAX = 100 after running the argument through the procedure `ran`. MY question is, does the `MOV EAX,100` replace the 123?

Also at the end of the procedure, I attaint the error. Is it because of the mov statement inside he procedure. please explain...

```
.code
main PROC
mov EAX, 123 ;Argument
MOV EBX, 456 ;Argument

call ran

     exit
main ENDP

ran PROC
     push eax ;save eax
     push ebx ;save ebx
     mov eax, 100 ;store 100 to eax?

     pop ebx
     ret
     exit
ran ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two push, but only one pop. Should be farily obvious why the exception occurs.

```
 push eax ;save eax
 push ebx ;save ebx
 mov eax, 100 ;store 100 to eax?

 pop ebx
 ret
```

If you `push` somthing on the stack, you must ensure that the stack balances by either manually adjusting it, or by using the same number of `pop` as you pushed before. In your case the `ret` instruction will jump somwhere where `eax` originally pointed to.

```
0x7b == 123  == eax
```